# Java - Create new file on remote location

Tags: java, file-io, remote-server

I need to create new file and put it into remote location like http://anyip:port/file/myfile.txt

Can you please help me to do this?

Regards

Comment: Are you in control of the remote server? Is it running an FTP server or an HTTP content amangement system, or something that will accept your upload?

Answer (score 0):

Shortly, no, it is impossible (although i would like to put my file into remote location `http://google.com/file/myfile.txt`).

More detailed: it depends on what the `anyip:port` server is. If it is your system, you may install for example an ftp server on it and put the files to ftp using java.

Comment: Actually I have one another machine and IP of that machine i am using in my machine. I have access on that machine via LAN. Tomcat server is running on my another machine and I have to put newly created file on another machine's tomcat root folder.Can u please help how can i put new file on other machine?

Comment: Login to that machine and put file to tomact->webapp->Root folder. But I needto move file using java code into other machine.

Comment: Then you should install some file server on the machine (e.g. FTP server like i have said before), configure it properly, and send files from java to that service.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it using FTP. There is a FTPClient available in java. It's as simple as this.

```
URL url = new URL("ftp://user01:pass1234@ftp.foo.com/README.txt;type=i");
URLConnection urlc = url.openConnection();
InputStream is = urlc.getInputStream(); // To download
OutputStream os = urlc.getOutputStream(); // To upload
```

There is a wonderful article [here](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-04-2003/jw-0404-ftp.html)